# How to get rid of re-appearing Dropbox Finder Toolbar button?

Tags: finder, dropbox

I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and have Dropbox 2.10.29 installed. For some reason I can't permanently remove the Dropbox button from the Finder toolbar.
I can remove it temporarily using `Customize Toolbar` or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+drag it from the toolbar, but as soon as I open a new Finder window it's back again.

If I quit Dropbox from the menubar and remove the button, the button stays gone even if I open another window. The moment I start Dropbox the button re-appears.

How can I permanently remove the button (pictured below on the right) from the Finder Toolbar?
[image]

I've contacted Dropbox, but I thought I would check if somebody here would have a solution in the mean time as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following procedure works on OS X Yosemite (10.10) and may also work on earlier versions of OS X:

- Right click on the toolbar and select the 'Customize Toolbar' menu item
- After the toolbar customisation sheet appears you should see that the Dropbox icon immediately follows two 'Flexible Space' items in the toolbar: [image: Toolbar with Dropbox icon]
- Remove the Dropbox icon by dragging it from the toolbar, and then repeat this action for one of the two flexible space items: [image: Toolbar with Dropbox icon removed]
- Close and reopen the finder window

---

Note: Disabling the `Enable Finder integration` option in Dropbox's preferences may remove the Dropbox icon from the Finder toolbar, however it also disables sync status icons and Dropbox contextual menu items from appearing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've uninstalled Dropbox since this problem appeared, so can't check if this works at the moment. Will do, if I re-install it again.

Comment: @BartArondson try option click the window close icon (the red on the screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

In Dropbox preferences, uncheck **Enable Finder Integration**

[image: Enable Finder Integration]

Comment: Unchecking the `Enable Finder integration` option does far more than remove the Dropbox icon from the Finder's toolbar, which was the request in the original question. It disables Dropbox sync status icons from appearing next to files and folders, and removes the contextual menu items for sharing links via Dropbox or opening files directly on Dropbox.