# Remove dropbox icon from Finder toolbar

Tags: macos, finder, dropbox

The dropbox icon keeps reappearing in my finder toolbar, no matter how many times I Command Drag it off, or remove it in customize toolbar.  How can I get rid of this annoying button that keeps coming back? [image: Toolbar with Dropbox icon]

The solution in [this one answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153034/5472) does not solve my issue as the button is removed, but as soon as I open a new finder window it is back.  I am running OS X 10.10.2 (14C81f) with Dropbox 3.0.3.

Comment: beta OS & out of date app, either could be responsible. Works fine for me on 10.10.1 & 3.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dropbox preferences, uncheck **Enable Finder Integration**

[image: Enable Finder Integration]