# How can I stop DropBox from being automatically added to the top of the sidebar in Finder?

Tags: finder, dropbox, sidebar

What it says on the tin. No matter whether I reorder my sidebar items or remove DropBox from my sidebar outright, it always reappears at the top of the sidebar upon login. I haven't found anything in the DropBox settings related to this, and neither have I found anything on Google. How can I stop this unwanted and intrusive behaviour without uninstalling DropBox, which I use for work?

Running macOS 10.15.7, if that matters.

I looked at [Remove dropbox icon from Finder toolbar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/165030/remove-dropbox-icon-from-finder-toolbar,but) this describes a different problem and the answers there are not applicable.